# Get x509 certificate hash with openssl library

Tags: c, hash, openssl, x509, libcrypto

I'm currently working on an app, which uses the openssl library (libcrypto) to generate certificates. Now I have to get the hash of a already existing certificate.

When I use my Terminal I am able to generate the hash value by using

```
openssl x509 -hash -in cert.pem -noout
```

> Output: 01da0e2b

This is my code where I try t generate my hash value by using the library in C.

```
X509 *cert = NULL;
FILE *fp = fopen(currentCert.UTF8String, "r");
PEM_read_X509(fp, &cert, NULL, NULL);

long hash = X509_subject_name_hash(cert);
char *mdString = malloc(sizeof(long));
sprintf(mdString, "%lx",hash);
printf(mdString);
```

> Output: 1817886a

But actually my output is a different one. Has anybody an idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: just use `printf("0x%08lx",hash)`, can not understand what is the reason to serialize it into char *, which is incorrect too because the size of the buffer should be dependent upon the number of digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But actually my output is a different one. Has anybody an idea what am I doing wrong ?

Here's how OpenSSL uses it...

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.2-src
$ grep -R X509_subject_name_hash *
apps/x509.c:                BIO_printf(STDout, "%08lx\n", X509_subject_name_hash(x));
apps/x509.c:                BIO_printf(STDout, "%08lx\n", X509_subject_name_hash_old(x));
crypto/x509/x509.h:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash(X509 *x);
crypto/x509/x509.h:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash_old(X509 *x);
crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash(X509 *x)
crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash_old(X509 *x)
...
```

Then, looking at `apps/x509.c`:

```
...
} else if (subject_hash == i) {
    BIO_printf(STDout, "%08lx\n", X509_subject_name_hash(x));
}
...
```

And your declaration should be:

```
unsigned long hash = X509_subject_name_hash(cert);
```

Then:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%08lx\n", hash);
```

---

Also, OpenSSL changed the way in calculates the subject hash sometime around OpenSSL 1.0.1. That's why there is an `X509_subject_name_hash` and `X509_subject_name_hash_old`.

If you are using or comparing against OpenSSL 0.9.8 (on, say Mac OS X 10), then see [Generate Subject Hash of X509Certificate in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265791/608639). Though its Java, it details OpenSSL handling of the subject hash.

Comment: Yes this works. Actually I discovered that, the server was using an old openssl library. So I had to use X509_subject_name_hash_old(cert);

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating enough memory for the string, although I can't be sure that is the cause of your problem.

```
char *mdString = malloc(sizeof(long));
```

will allocate 4 bytes to the string, yet it clearly needs to hold 8 bytes plus a terminator, so I suggest

```
char *mdString = malloc(sizeof(long)*2 + 1);
```

Comment: I think you are right, but, actually I get the same output.
"1817886a"