# Generate Subject Hash of X509Certificate in Java

Tags: java, hash, openssl, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I'm currently trying to generate the subject hash by using the Java Security API and BouncyCastle.

Here's what I do, when I use the Openssl Library:

```
openssl x509 -in  /Users/Sn0wfreezeDev/Downloads/Test.pem -hash
```

This generates a short 8 digit hash *1817886a*

This is my Java code

```
X509Certificate cert = CertManager.getCertificate(number, c);  
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
System.out.println("  Subject " + cert.getSubjectDN());
System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
sha1.update(cert.getSubjectDN().getName().getBytes());
String hexString =  bytesToHex(sha1.digest());
System.out.println("   sha1    " + hexString);
System.out.println();
```

Comment: You will need the Subject Distinguished Name. For that (in Java), see [Getting the Subject and Issuer Distinguished Names of an X509 Certificate](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/GettingtheSubjectandIssuerDistinguishedNamesofanX509Certificate.htm).

Comment: Can you provide the final code the is working?

Comment: I'm using `byte []sha1Bytes0_3 = Arrays.copyOfRange( sha1.digest(), 0, 4);  String hexString =   getHex(sha1Bytes0_3);` but getting diffrent hash than the one computed by openssl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This generates a short 8 digit hash 1817886a

There are two forms of this from OpenSSL:

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.2-src
$ grep -R X509_subject_name_hash *
...
crypto/x509/x509.h:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash(X509 *x);
crypto/x509/x509.h:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash_old(X509 *x);
crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash(X509 *x)
crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash_old(X509 *x)
...
```

---

> Generate Subject Hash of X509Certificate in Java...

Here is the source for them from `crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c`:

```
unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash(X509 *x)
{
    return (X509_NAME_hash(x->cert_info->subject));
}

#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_MD5
unsigned long X509_subject_name_hash_old(X509 *x)
{
    return (X509_NAME_hash_old(x->cert_info->subject));
}
#endif
```

And finally:

```
unsigned long X509_NAME_hash(X509_NAME *x)
{
    unsigned long ret = 0;
    unsigned char md[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    /* Make sure X509_NAME structure contains valid cached encoding */
    i2d_X509_NAME(x, NULL);
    if (!EVP_Digest(x->canon_enc, x->canon_enclen, md, NULL, EVP_sha1(),
                    NULL))
        return 0;

    ret = (((unsigned long)md[0]) | ((unsigned long)md[1] << 8L) |
           ((unsigned long)md[2] << 16L) | ((unsigned long)md[3] << 24L)
        ) & 0xffffffffL;
    return (ret);
}

#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_MD5
unsigned long X509_NAME_hash_old(X509_NAME *x)
{
    EVP_MD_CTX md_ctx;
    unsigned long ret = 0;
    unsigned char md[16];

    /* Make sure X509_NAME structure contains valid cached encoding */
    i2d_X509_NAME(x, NULL);
    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&md_ctx);
    EVP_MD_CTX_set_flags(&md_ctx, EVP_MD_CTX_FLAG_NON_FIPS_ALLOW);
    if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(&md_ctx, EVP_md5(), NULL)
        && EVP_DigestUpdate(&md_ctx, x->bytes->data, x->bytes->length)
        && EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&md_ctx, md, NULL))
        ret = (((unsigned long)md[0]) | ((unsigned long)md[1] << 8L) |
               ((unsigned long)md[2] << 16L) | ((unsigned long)md[3] << 24L)
            ) & 0xffffffffL;
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&md_ctx);

    return (ret);
}
#endif
```

---

[`i2d_X509_NAME`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/i2d_x509_name) encodes a `X509_NAME` into a standard representation using [RFC 2459](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2459) (and elsewhere). Its used, for example, in certificate subject and issuer names.

You can see what OpenSSL uses for the name string with commands like `openssl x509 -in <cert> -text -noout`. It will look similar to `C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=www.google.com` (taken from a Google certificate).

---

> Generate Subject Hash of X509Certificate in Java...

In the big picture, you are generating a hash of the Subject's Distinguished Name string and returning an unsigned long. The unsigned long is effectively a truncated hash.

`X509_subject_name_hash` uses SHA-1, and `X509_subject_name_hash_old` uses MD5.

---

> (comment) ... how they can use a sha1 hash to generate that short hash

OpenSSL provides a hex encoding of a truncated hash. The whole hash is in `md`. `md` will be 16 bytes (MD5) or 20 bytes (SHA-1).

The truncation occurs with the selection of bytes `[0,3]` and the bit operations on `md[0]`, `md[1]`, `md[2]` and `md[3]`.

The 8 digits comes from hex encoding the 4 bytes.

Comment: Okay so how is it possible for me to get the same 8 digit hash in Java ?

Comment: I know I've found the OpenSSL code, too. But I don't get how they can use a sha1 hash to generate that short hash

Comment: Does anybody have an idea how to do this in Bash? I know about `x509 -hash` and `-issuer_hash` . Getting the exact source data is what I'm looking for.