# Generate OpenSSL subject_name hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, openssl, sha1

I've investigated [30261296](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261296/generate-subject-hash-of-x509certificate-in-java) however I'm still at a loss to find a way to generate the same results in Ruby with the openssl and/or digest gems. The OpenSSL output I'm trying to replicate in ruby is as follows:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash -in DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.pem
85cf5865
```

In reading many things, I believe this hash is generated from the Subject:  portion of the certificate, which is like the distinguished name. In this certificates case something to the effect of:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -subject -in DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt
subject=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
```

Attempting to SHA-1 encode that on the command line or in Ruby (which represents this as `/C=US,/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA` when using the openssl gem) has not yeilded the same has results displayed by OpenSSL.

I'm trying to do this more natively in Ruby to avoid shelling out to openssl if possible since openssl and digest come along with the ruby env. In the end I need this to generate the hash directory tree ... i.e. `85cf5865.0` (hash + '.0').

The CA I'm hasing is [DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt](https://dl.cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt) - DER encoded. I converted DER to PEM because openssl command line uses that without the additional `-inform der` switch. It doesn't appear to matter to Ruby's openssl gem.

Comment: There's an answer for [Java here](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/125892f). It looks like a royal pain, I'd choose to shell out to openssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be pretty straightforward, since Ruby’s OpenSSL bindings includes the [`OpenSSL::X509::Name#hash` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Name.html#method-i-hash), which is exactly what we want.

```
require 'openssl'

# Read the certificate.
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.binread("DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt"))

# Get the subject, which is an OpenSSL::X509::Name object.
name = cert.subject

# hash returns an integer, we want the hex string so call to_s(16).
puts name.hash.to_s(16) #=> 85cf5865
```

The integer will be positive since OpenSSL returns an unsigned int, so we can just use `to_s(16)` and don’t need to worry about converting negative values.

Comment: Wow I had no clue I was somewhat close... couldn't figure out that it was the hash of the integer hash. Thanks!