# Incorrect OpenSSL subject hash

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, hash, openssl

**Background**

OpenSSL has implemented a filename technique to reduce the Certificate Authority (CA) look-up time. Without this approach it would be required to read all CA files in the CApath to find the matching certificate.

Using the subject hash we can softlink to a certificate by appending '.0' to the subject hash (e.g e5d93f80.0).  If there is more than one CA file with same subject hash value, their extensions should differ (e.g. e5d93f80.1). The search is performed in the order of the extension number; lowest to highest.

Two known methods are available `openssl` and `c_rehash`.

**Method One**

```
$ openssl x509 -in certs/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem -noout -subject_hash
594f1775
$ ln -s certs/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem 594f1775.0
```

**Method Two**

```
$ c_rehash certs/
Doing certs/
Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem => 594f1775.0
```

**Resources**

[Equifax Secure Certificate Authority PEM](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem)

**Environment**

- OS X El Capitan
- Clang Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
- OpenSSL 1.0.2e-dev

**Problem**

The subject hash produced appears to be incorrect when using [boost::asio client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp).

Using `dtruss` shows that it attempts to load one of 578d5c04.0, 2c543cd1.0, c4c7a654.0 subject hash files.

```
$ sudo dtruss ./client www.google.com /
Password:

Resolve OK
Connect OK 
Handshake failed: certificate verify failed
...
stat64("./certs/578d5c04.0\0", 0x7FFF5CEBC7D0, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("./certs/2c543cd1.0\0", 0x7FFF5CEBC7D0, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("./certs/c4c7a654.0\0", 0x7FFF5CEBC7D0, 0x0)      = -1 Err#2
write_nocancel(0x1, "Handshake failed: certificate verify failed\n\0", 0x2C)         = 44 0
...
close(0x5)       = 0 0
```

If I rename the symbolic link to one of these filenames everything works perfectly.

How do we generate the correct subject hash?

Comment: OpenSSL changed the algorithm used for `c_rehash` a while back... It stopped using MD5 and began using SHA. More recently, it fixed a Subject Name lookup problem. My ***guess*** is there's a disconnect between what you think your are using (1.0.2e) and what is being used by, say, Boost. Finally, OpenSSL changed the way it creates certificate hashes, so `-subject_hash` may be producing different results than you expect; see [Get x509 certificate hash with openssl library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30059107).

Comment: Here's what I get for `which c_rehash` on OS X 10.8: `/usr/bin/c_rehash`. You are likely using the `c_rehash` from Apple's OpenSSL 0.9.8. OpenSSL 0.9.8 uses the MD5 algorithm, while OpenSSL 1.0 and above uses SHA1. Also see [Question regarding openssl program to compute the hashes and finger-prints](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Question-regarding-openssl-program-to-compute-the-hashes-and-finger-prints-td45095.html) on the OpenSSL mailing list.

Comment: @jww that's very much answer material IMO

Comment: @jww Having previously validated that multiple versions of the dependency were not getting tied-up, I'm skeptical.  I will however try again; more than likely I've made a mistake.  I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: @Corvusoft - How did you  make out on this? I don't have OS X 10.10, so I can't test anything (hence the reason I could only offer suggestions).

Comment: @jww Apologies. We've been caught up with a product release.  Will look into this again today and get back to you.

Comment: @jww Right you are.  Thought I had two installations but found a third in '/usr/local/ssl/lib/'.  Please create an answer so I can assign and close off this question.  Thanks ;)

Comment: Also see [Generate Subject Hash of X509Certificate in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30265791/608639). Though its Java, it details OpenSSL handling of the subject hash.